# Modal a viewController inside the containerView

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I have a containerView that embedded a UIViewController (named embedVC).

In the embedVC, I want to modal another ViewController (named modalVC), I wish the modalVC just cover the embedVC.

How should I do?

2017-03-16:

I have a try to just use view with EmbeddedVC to simulate the modal. But I have a problem:

Before modal:
[image]

After modal:
[image]

My Design:
[image]

So I think I still need a real modal segue to bring the modalView to front.

Answer (score 1):

> I wish the modalVC just cover the embedVC

Instead of a using a *modal* UIViewController, a `UIView` presented with appropriate animating effects enclosing only the bounds of `embedVC` can be implemented.

Comment: Thank you very much. You reminds me of that may the ViewController have another view in storyboard (the view is not in self.view, it's just a outlet in viewcontroller). I will get a try later, then I will come back to feedback the results.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. After the experiment, I found that this is not a fit for me. My embedVC have some other UIView mask it. I have upload some screen capture to explain the situation.

Comment: @PMExtra you can evaluate trying a combination of  `bringSubviewToFront:`, `view.hidden = true` or `view.alpha = 0` to hide the undesired views.

Comment: The undesired views is in superView.superView.superView.subviews，I think I hard to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Let try to present this modal as a popover with anchor point is embed view and also set it's frame.